# What is nonhomogeneous linear mapping?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

In Milnor's *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint*, page 3, he said:

> One thinks of the nonhomogeneous linear mapping from the tangent hyperplane at $x$ to the tangent hyperplane at $y$ which best approximates $f$. Translating both hyperplanes to the origin, one obtains $df_x$.

What is nonhomogeneous linear mapping? As far as I know, linear maps are all homogeneous.

Comment: He probably meant "affine". Then an affine map is homogeneous iff it is linear.

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Comment: Peter: This is the only thing which makes sense in this context.

Comment: @studiosus: can you put that as an answer? The continuation of the text makes this clearer. I have taken the liberty of editing it in to the question, though it will wait for peer review.

Comment: @SamLisi: Done.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable interpretation of a linear map in this context is the one of an affine map. A homogeneous affine map would be linear in the conventional sense. This is similar to the terminology one uses for systems of linear equations $Ax+b=0$. The left hand side is an affine map and the system is called homogeneous if $b=0$. Also in calculus we frequently call a map $ax+b$ linear even though, strictly speaking, this map is affine.